# How would you change this statement to allow it to work no matter what the response is?

Tags: c#

I tried using `== true || false` but I'm not sure if that was the wrong way to type it out or what but I can't get the response to display unless the answer is the value tied to the Boolean of true.

```
public ViewResult ListResponses() {
 //return View(Repository.Responses);
 return View(Repository.Responses.Where(r => r.ParkingRequest == true));
}
```

Comment: It'll be better if you show some more code to understand your problem

Comment: Why bother filtering with Where if you don't really want to filter?

Comment: `true || false` is always true, it doesn't filter on "either true or false"

Comment: Just remove the `Where`....

Comment: It seems that you are coming from JS and trying to validate data like you do in JS. But C# is a strongly typed language and such expressions make no sense for it. In that case I'd suggest you to learn C# basics first.

Comment: Why this question is tagged JavaScript and HTML?